# I need community perspective in regards to Jenkins Salesforce CI setup for deployments with ant Migration tool

Tags: salesforcedx, ant, jenkins, cicd, jenkinsfile

I could not invoke ant from Jenkins.

I am new to this CI/CD, I was able to invoke ant from cmd but I could not do it with jenkins. If I need to upload futher code, please let me know.

The error is referring to this line in my build.xml file:

`<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="fetcheddata" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">`

**Error:**

````
Target "fetcheddata" does not exist in the project "Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks". 

Total time: 1 second
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE```
````

Comment: consider using [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) instead of old ant metadata. sfdx is a new tool with all capabilities of ant and has additional useful functionality.

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi, it is working with sfdx, thank you for the advice. How to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to invest time in an old tool `ant migration tool`, I recommend you take a look at [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli). sfdx is a new tool with all capabilities of ant and has additional useful functionality. Here is a [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference.htm) with detailed instructions on how to work with it. Here is just a few examples of deploying metadata.

deploy sfdx metadata format `sfdx force:source:deploy -p path/to/source`

retrieve sfdx format metadata from org `sfdx force:source:retrieve -p path/to/source`